# SAML2.0 to SAML1.1 translation with ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-server, sso

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and want to connect it to ADFS on Windows Server 2016.

I also have a 3rd-party Identity Provider, which support SAML2.0.
The problem is Sharepoint 2013 only support SAML1.1, so do we have any way to config ADFS as a translator between SAML2.0 (from 3rd party IdP) to SAML1.1 and send it to Sharepoint? If yes, please help me the template config.

I tried many times with this model. If I login using AD user via ADFS, it's ok, but if from 3rd party IdP, I get the error: The trusted login provider did not supply a token accepted by this farm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then the following steps should help you:

- **ADFS**: Add SharePoint as *Relying Party Trust*
- **ADFS**: Add 3rd party IdP as *Claims Provider Trust*
- **3rd party IdP**: Add ADFS as *RP*
- **3rd party IdP**: Configure claim issuance policy to issue claim that of the same type as *IdentifierClaim* specified in SharePoint
- **ADFS**: On SharePoint RP trust add two *claim issuance rules*:

  1. *Send LDAP attributes as Claims* (select the same type that SharePoint needed as IdentifierClaim)
  2. *Pass-Through an Incoming Claim* (all claim values)